# Bigtable column family time range scan returning all rows regardless of timestamp

Tags: hbase, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I am trying to use a `ColumnFamilyTimeRange` on my `Scan` to read only recent rows from Bigtable. However, the scan returns all rows no matter what I set the time range to.

I have one column family. Here's what I'm seeing: I add a new row with a value for that column family, then wait, then add another new row. I then do a read from Bigtable with a `Scan` with an ordinary (ie not column family specific) `TimeRange` set. It correctly returns only the recently added row.

However, when I change that `TimeRange` to a `ColumnFamilyTimeRange` with the same timestamp bounds and the only column family I have, I get back every row. Even when I set the timestamp bounds to something nonsensical (such as before I even created the table), I still get back every row.

Is this a bug or am I completely missing how `ColumnFamilyTimeRange` is meant to work?

Answer (score 2):

Currently timestamp range scans on column families are not supported. Unfortunately there are differences from the HBase API. You can check them [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-differences).

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is not ideal. We shouldn't silently drop the ColumnFamilyTimeRange.

I added https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-bigtable-client/issues/2184 to track the issue. In the mean time I would recommend to use a combination of FilterList(MUST_PASS_ALL), TimestampRangeFilter and FamilyFilter filters to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Hey thanks Igor! Is it possible to use a filter like that but have it return the whole row if any cells match, and nothing if no cells match? So for example, if I had a row like:
`row_key_123 | col_1_value | col_2_value` and I wanted to get the row only if `col_1` had been updated recently, would that be possible?

Comment: This is supported by Bigtable, but is not exposed in the hbase api. If you need this functionality, I would encourage you to take a look a the native Bigtable client: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-bigtable. The Query object lets you set native Bigtable filters, one which is a condition: https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/bigtable/data/v2/models/Filters.html#condition-com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.models.Filters.Filter-.

Comment: Thanks so much Igor! That has exactly what I was looking for. Just as an FYI though, I think there's a bug with the timestamp filter. If you use timestamp range with `.startOpen`, it adds 1 to the time value (presumably to make it "open"). However, it then throws an error saying `Timestamp granularity mismatch. Expected a multiple of 1000 (millisecond granularity), but got <timestamp ending in 001>`